# jquery find the next/nearest multiple number of another number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<table>` with dynamically generated rows (`<tr>’s`).

In each row, I have a particular cell (`<td>`) in which I display a textbox. Within that textbox, I’ve added a custom `data-roundingrule` attribute which holds a particular value (in each row, the data-roundingrule attribute may (or may not) have a different value).

Here are two examples of what those textboxes might look like:

```
<input type=”text” id=”txt-1” name=”txt-1” data-roundingrule=”2”>
<input type=”text” id=”txt-2” name=”txt-2” data-roundingrule=”13”>
```

My goal is to create a change event on every textbox that verifies if the entered value (by the user) is a multiple of the value stored in the `data-roundingrule` attribute.

If the entered value by the user is a multiple of the `data-roundingrule` attribute then great! Leave things as is…

If the entered value by the user is not a multiple of the `data-roundingrule` attribute then find/get/obtain the next nearest number that will be a multiple of the `data-roundingrule` attribute.

Here’s an example:

Considering the above two textboxes, in textbox 1, the user enters the value 1. The change event verifies if the value 1 is a multiple of the data-roundingrule set to 2. Since it’s not the case, then I need to change the value entered by the user and set it to 2.

Likewise for the second textbox…assuming the user has entered the value 4 in the textbox, 4 is not a multiple of 13, so I need to change the user’s input from a 4 to a 13.

If the user has entered the value 16 in the second textbox, 16 is not a multiple of 13 so I need to change the user’s input from a 16 to a 26 (which is the next multiple).

Hope this makes sense…

Sincerely and thanks in advance!

Comment: So far I have the change event which calls another function. That other function gets the user input for that particular textbox in addition to the value inside the data-roundingrule attribute. With that, I capable of figuring out if the user’s input is a multiple but what I haven’t figured out is how to find the next/nearest multiple in case the user’s input is not a multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var rr = parseInt($(this).data('roundingrule'), 10);
    if ($(this).val() % rr != 0) $(this).val(Math.ceil($(this).val() / rr) * rr);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EMEyv/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var round     = parseInt($(this).attr('data-roundingrule'), 10);
    var value     = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var remainder = value % round;

    if(remainder != 0) {
        $(this).val(value + round - remainder);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onchange method

```
<input type=”text” id=”txt-2” name=”txt-2” data-roundingrule=”13” onchange="roundUp(this)">
```

And then defined the function like so with Jquery...

```
function roundUp(el)
{
  var num = $(this).attr("data-roundingrule");
  num = num * 1 // lazy coercion to numeric type

  var val = $(this).attr(val);

  val = val * 1;
  if(val % num === 0)
  {
    //it's good
  }
  else
  {
    while(val % num !== 0)
    {
      val += 1;
    }
  }  
}
```

You should probably add some kind of error checking though...